# How to show reminder only on specific date in React

Tags: reactjs, date, filter, reminders, react-calendar

In a component, I have a Calendar using react-calendar on the left side. I can add reminders via a form where I can select a date. These two dates are different displayed: the date from the react-calender is shown in the format 18/08/2021 while the date from the reminder form is shown as 2021-08-18.

How can I compare these two values so that only reminders are shown on the specific date when clicking on a calendar date? I tried to parse (which seems to be not recommended by MDN) but the output numbers are different. I tried to compare with valueOf() but the output is false.

**EDIT:**

I was able to compare both dates and the output is true. Therefore, I set a new prop to reminder "show" with the state of "false". But when I try to return this prop as true when both dates are the same, the prop does not change. (changing it manually with dev tools, the show/hide function works now perfectly fine).

In my index.js file, I created an onChange function when clicking a specific date in the calendar:

```
const onCalendarChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
    reminders.map((item) => {
      const itemDate = item.date
        .toLocaleString()
        .slice(0, 10)
        .replace(/\D/g, "");
      const calDate = date.toLocaleDateString().split("/").reverse().join("");
      console.log(itemDate === calDate);
      if (itemDate === calDate) {
        return {
          ...item,
          show: true,
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
  };
```

I also tried it with the filter() but this does not seem to work either. The reminders are shown the whole time.

```
 const onCalendarChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
    setReminders(
      reminders.filter(
        (item) =>
          item.date.toLocaleString().slice(0, 10).replace(/\D/g, "") ===
          date.toLocaleDateString().split("/").reverse().join("")
      )
    );
  };
```

Comment: Could be passed as `Date` format?

Answer (score 1):

**1. First code snippet:**

The first code snippet may not be working because you forgot to store the new array in a variable and reset `reminders` on the state using it (which you did correctly in the second code snippet).

So, the first code snippet should be something like this:

```
const updatedReminders = reminders.map((item) => {
      // logic here
});

setReminders(updatedReminders);
```

**2. Second Code Snippet:**

Not sure why this isn't working, YET. I'll let you know when I have an update.

In the meantime, see if my suggestion for the first code snippet does the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This does not seem to work either, but made me realize that the problem might lie somewhere else. I do have the exact same map function on my reminder for "completed: false" which will be set to "completed true" when clicking a checkbox, which works perfectly fine. The difference would be that this function is declared in the reminder component itself (to check the reminder), while the "show" map function is declared in the parent, where the Calendar onClick will be.